# tikzposter and doi package conflict?

Tags: hyperref, doi, tikzposter

When using the `doi` package with `tikzposter`, I get the following error when compiling with `pdflatex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.4 \HyperFirstAtBeginDocument
                              {\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
?
```

However, if I kill the failed compilation and run `pdflatex` a second time without deleting the `*.aux` file then it compiles successfully.

Is this a known conflict, and is there any way to fix this so that it compiles the first time? Thanks in advance for your help.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{doi}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `doi` is not involved other than it loads `hyperref` you get the same error if you change `doi` to `hyperref` in the above

Answer (score 10):

Looks like a hyperref or tikz bug (not fully tracked it down) but you can do this:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{doi}


\def\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The additional line should be the last thing in the preamble, just before `\begin{document}`

Comment: tikzposter adds \begin{tikzpicture} to \AtBeginDocument and \end{tikzpicture} to \AtEndDocument and so introduce a group. Not quite sure if this is a good idea ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh excellent, thanks!  that means it's a tikz bug not a hyperref one, so I don't have to fix it:-)

Comment: ; -). Imho there is somewhere here a discussion regarding environments in begin/end document but can't look now, I'm off to dinner...

Comment: Note adding the definition just before \begin{document} may not work if you have e.g. a \setitle{} in the preamble that requires hyperlinks. At least, I found placing it just after all packages were loaded was required to get error-free compilation.