# incompatibility between tikzposter class, microtype and hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, microtype, tikzposter

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254257/tikzposter-and-doi-package-conflict
\def\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}

\title{Title}
\institute{Inst}
\author{Auth}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Blocktitle}{Text}

\end{document}
```

Error messages:

```
./test.tex:18: Undefined control sequence.
\pdfstringdefPreHook ->\MT@ltx@pickupfont
                                          \let \textmicrotypecontext \@secon...
l.18 \end{document}
```

This is different than [incompatibility between tikzposter class and microtype package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165846/incompatibility-between-tikzposter-class-and-microtype-package)

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

tikzposter inserts with `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` a center and tikzpicture enviroment, and this introduce groups. This is not a good idea and one of the bad side effects is that this breaks the microtype. You can get similar error with this simpler example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{\begingroup}
\AtEndDocument{\endgroup}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 text
\end{document}
```

I don't see a sensible workaround, it doesn't help to use `\center` and `\tikzpicture` in the code, as `\tikzpicture` creates a group in any case. I suggest to use something else for the poster, e.g. the poster library from tcolorbox.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I don't understand why having groups in `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` is bad.

Comment: It is bad as it breaks things as you can see in your example.